# Limit the number of list elements to add inside a nested list jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hy. I have a list in which when I press the "add" button that corresponds to the specific `li` element, it will add a child to that `li`. I want to limit the number of children that I can add to all `li` elements.
For example I want to be able to add maximum 2 child nodes to the right of `list1`.
I should be able to press the "add" button near `list1`, then the "add" button near `childNode1` and stop it there. Similar to `list2`

I tried stuff like:

```
 var listItems = $('ul').children().length;;
 alert(listItems);
```

but it will output the total number of list elements inside the main `<ul>` every time I add a new `list element`. 
   [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CfY5b/25/).

Comment: Think about giving a complet base with your html and maybe more JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

youre way was correct. just put it in an if statement and set the number of the length.

```
    var childLimiter = 2;
    var listItems = $('ol').children('li').length;
    if(listItems <= childLimiter){
        $(this).parent().append('<ol><li>child node<input type="button" value="add" /></li></ol>');      
    } else {
        $(this).parent().append('<ol><li>child node</li></ol>');
    }
```

see updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CfY5b/26/)

greetings timotheus

Comment: I have tested the code a bit and there is an issue. Instead of "childLimiter" i would need a "levelLimiter" so that all children that are on the first level of `list1` and `list2` must have an "add" button. All the children that are on the second level of`list1` and `list2` should not have the "add" button. Any idea how it can be done?

Comment: the simplest solution would be if you give the first ol in your dom a class. for instance "ol--start" and than you just have to change the if 
from: if(listItems <= childLimiter){ 
to: if($(this).parent().parent('ol').hasClass('startingOl')){ working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CfY5b/27/

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution. It works now. If I want to extend it with more children levels with buttons I just have to put another `if clause` which appends a `ol class="Level2"`.